# How to make scroll in every <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajayraturi/85f8zjeh/1/)

in this i have a scroll in `top` and `middle` that was fine.
but as you see in middle there was a scroll also there but it doesn't work for me. i want that every `<tr>` have there own scroll.

Comment: no that fine in my workstation. i am talking about the middle scroll with the text 'Total12'.